# Combine two XML documents with similar schema

Tags: xslt

I have two XML documents that need to be combined in special way.

As a simple example I'll just put both documents into one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
    <config1>
        <option1 type="a">A</option1>
        <option2 type="b">B</option2>
        <option3 type="c">C</option3>
    </config1>
    <config2>
        <option2 type="bb">BB</option2>
        <option4>D</option4>
    </config2>
</data>
```

So, i need to merge *config1* and *config2* to this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <config>
    <option1 type="a">A</option1>
    <option2 type="bb">BB</option2>
    <option3 type="c">C</option3>
    <option4>D</option4>
  </config>
</data>
```

Transformation rules are:

1. Get option from *config1* if there is no such option in *config2*
2. Otherwise get that option from *config2*
3. Get options from *config2* if they are not present in *config1*

i've made following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <config>
        <!-- Select options from config 1. -->
        <xsl:for-each select="config1/*">
          <xsl:choose>
            <!-- Leave option as is. -->
            <xsl:when test="not(/data/config2/*[name() = name(current())])">
              <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- Overwrite option. -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:copy-of select="/data/config2/*[name() = name(current())]"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <!-- Select options from config 2. -->
        <xsl:for-each select="config2/*">
          <!-- Append "new" option -->
          <xsl:if test="not(/data/config1/*[name()=name(current())])">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </config>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works, but looks lame.

Many XSL gurus prefer apply-templates over for-each.

Is it possible to rewrite my template in that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As a simple example I'll just put both documents into one:

That's not a good idea, because dealing with two documents is not the same as dealing with two node-sets in the same document. So, assuming your processed document is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
    <config1>
        <option1 type="a">A</option1>
        <option2 type="b">B</option2>
        <option3 type="c">C</option3>
    </config1>
</data>
```

and there is another document:

**file2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
    <config2>
        <option2 type="bb">BB</option2>
        <option4>D</option4>
    </config2>
</data>
```

you could use the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="config2" select="document('file2.xml')/data/config2" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <data>
        <config>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="data/config1/*[not(name()=name($config2/*))] | $config2/*"/>
        </config>
    </data>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data/*/*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to obtain this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
   <config>
      <option1 type="a">A</option1>
      <option3 type="c">C</option3>
      <option2 type="bb">BB</option2>
      <option4>D</option4>
   </config>
</data>
```